# Why it skips the last character of string

Tags: python

I have a problem in this code.

Why it skips the last character of my string. Lets say I want to calculate a hash for "timeGetTime", the loop stops at 'e' character.

I tried to print the API name and it prints all characters correctly.

### Edit:

correct hash is `0xFF407C2F` but the output is `0xE07FFA03`

```
def ROR(data, shift, size=32):
    shift %= size
    body = data >> shift
    remains = (data << (size - shift)) - (body << size)
    return (body + remains)


def calculateHash(apiName):
    result = 0
    for ch in apiName:
        result = ROR(result, 0x13)
        result +=  ord(ch)

    return result
```

Comment: Pls, elaborate on your problem, what you are trying to accomplish, how the code is working, etc. Also, show the input which you are sending as parameters to the function.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish read the question, everything you said is mentioned.

Comment: I tried to print this string and it prints 'e' so why it stops here and doesn't continue this algorithm

Comment: The answer below (which you should accept) identifies the problem. A good debugging strategy would have been to evaluate things like `calculateHash("A")` (strings of length 1) -- then you would have hopefully realized that you were just calculating `ord("A")` with no call to `ROR`.

Comment: What is the correct has for `"A"`? How does one go about determining what a correct hash is? I really think that the answer below adequately explains the skipping part. You now have a different question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the order of the lines so that the last letter also gets the results of the other function -

```
for ch in apiName:
    result +=  ord(ch)
    result = ROR(result, 0x13) # What you did was change the result later
```

Comment: I'm trying to reverse engineer some hashes so the order of lines is matter.
btw, I doesn't work also :(

Comment: What happens when you run this?

Comment: @Raafat if this doesn't fix the problem, it would *really* help if you gave intended output and not just input. This answer explains why the last character isn't hashed -- which is exactly the problem that you identified.

Comment: If there is any problem with the logic of your `ROR` function, then it forms a different question. Ask a new question in that case.

Comment: It also skips the last character. In my example, I want to make last ROR operation to calculate the correct hash

Comment: Wait, what is the correct hash for "timeGetTime", you need to mention the output.

Comment: I edited my post with output